# SSH Connection Refused during Installing CentOS

Tags: centos, installation

I am re-installing CentOS 6.6 to upgrade from 5.6. I was using SSH and VNC to install the CentOS. Thus, I was trying to install CentOS 6.6 remotely. I tried to follow instructions in this link: http://www.centosx.com/install-centos-6-6-remotely-vnc-dedicated-servers/#comment-6170 After I did reboot before connecting VNC, I cannot connect to either SSH or VNC to install the CentOS.

When I try ssh, I get following message:

> ssh: connect to host ***.******.*** port 22: Connection refused

When I try VNC, I get following message

> The connection was refused by the host computer

Is there any way I can connect to the SSH or VNC?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check for iptables?

Comment: @PetterH I didn't. I just followed the instruction from the link. I cannot do it now, because the server refuse my connection.